# Problemas con la solictud Post hecha python desde un formulario hecho en laravel

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo un formulario hecho en `laravel` hecho con el método `POST` el cual es el siguiente

```
<form method="POST">    
{{ csrf_field() }}

    <input type="email" name="email">   
    <input type="password" name="password">     
    <input type="submit" value="ingresar" >

 </form>
```

Pero cuando quiero acceder a una solicitud `post` con `python` usando la librería `urllib, el cuál el código es el siguiente:

```
import urllib2
import urllib

while 1:

    url = "http://192.168.1.10/login"
    query_args = { 'email':'algun_email@algundominio.com','password':'123456'}
    data =urllib.urlencode(query_args)
    request = urllib2.Request (url,data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    print response
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> File "urlx2.py", line 10, in 
>            response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
>            return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
>            response = meth(req, response)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
>            'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
>            return self._call_chain(*args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
>            result = func(*args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
>            raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>       urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

Todas está correctamente. Creo que es un problema del `CSRF_TOKEN` de `Laravel`, ya que funciona correctamente con la solictud `GET` sin el `CSRF_TOKEN`.No creo que sea el problema con la solicitud `POST`, ya que lo he hecho con una formulario hecho en `PHP` y funciona correctamente.

Cómo podría implementar esa Solitud `POST` con el `URLLIB` de `PYTHON`

Comment: ese error 500 puede ser todo

Comment: de hecho puede ser problema de CORS, busca el log de apache2 para verificar

Comment: Parece que la parte python es correcta, sólo que el servidor en lugar de darle la respuesta esperada le da un error 500. Este error indica que el proceso php  ha "roto", probablemente al intentar acceder a un elemento de un objeto que no existe. Sospecho que es porque el script python no le envía todos los campos del formulario que el scrip PHP esperaba, en concreto los campos ocultos que habrá generado como parte del código `{{ csrf_field() }}`. Supongo que python tiene que hacer antes un GET de esa url para obtener esos campos. Usando `requests` sería más fácil,